# Emergency Publish - to a different location

Tags: deployer, deployer-extension

In our production environment, with current implementation, when Tridion publishes the content, deployer writes the binary file contents to a location (say location A) in staging environment.

Files from this location A will be read & pushed to Production ready environment only once on daily basis .

But in case if business wants to update any binary content during the business hours to reflect IMMEDIATELY in Production ready environment (Emergency Publish) - this is not happening as the process of pushing the files to Production ready environment happens only once on a day.

To over come this, the suggestion is - during Emergency Publish to publish the content to a different location (Say location B) and files published to this location will be written to Production ready environment immediately.

What is the best way to publish files to a different location during emergency situation?
Please note  - During normal publish, it should continue to publish the file to location A.

Do we need to create a separate deployer module to achieve this (in addition to the existing deployer module)?

Need suggestion, Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your scenario looks little unconventional  to me, don't you publish on the Production environment, just take the binary dump from Staging? Yes new deployer is one of the solution. but keep the environment in sync

Comment: Editors can publish to Staging, which means the changes will become "Live" by tomorrow. A new separate Target would probably be confusing to editors with something like "Live (Right Away)." I highly suspect your editors would ignore *Slow Staging* in favor of *Fast Live*.

Comment: Do you still have access to the architect who specified this setup?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have specific requirements and constraints for when "EMERGENCY" publishing is allowed, I would recommend removing the daily publishing constraint, which sounds like a technical or architectural constraint rather than a business requirement.

You'll have a bit of extra work to prevent editors from always choosing Live given two options:

- Staging (publishes later)
- Live (go live now)

*In other words, how would you prevent editors from **always** choosing Live?*

I don't automatically recommend workflow as the solution for all publishing requirements, but consider it if you have publishing requirements related to dates, metadata, and suspending activities.

Answer (score 3):

Although, there are multiple options to achieve this which may depends on detailed business requirements and the specific business restrictions you may have, but the best bet in "my opinion" would be to create a separate Publishing Target (and Target Types) and a separate deployer module in addition to your existing deployer. You may want to change the location of binary publish in this new deployer in the cd_storage_config xml file.

May be you want to explain more in your question, what about other content apart from the binary and how you actually publish content to Live (apart from binary) currently